# Do all logics have formula syntax specified by context-free grammar?

Tags: logic, context-free-grammar

I think propositional logic formulas syntax could be specified by context-free grammar with production rule below, where $A$ generates a finite string of $a_0, a_1$ stands for an atomic formula variable.

$$S \to\,\, \sim\!\! S \mid ( S \& S ) \mid A$$
$$A \to\,\, Aa_0 \mid Aa_1 \mid \epsilon$$

Are there any other kinds of logic that have formulas syntax that couldn't be specified by context-free grammar?

edit:
Edited the CFG production rules for propositional logic to produce a countable infinite number of atomic formula variables.

edit2:
Rewording the question as "Do all logics have formula syntax specified by context-free grammar?"

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would say that any "usual" logic can be specified by a context free grammar.

however there is no restriction in the definition of a logic for example let me introduce you the Wece logic defined as follow:
$\phi$ is a formula of the wece formula if and only if it can be written as $\psi\psi\psi$ where $\psi$ is a formula of propositional logic.

The evaluation of $\phi$ is given as the evaluation of $\psi$ in propositional logic.

This logic (totally useless) is well define but not context free.

(sorry I didn't think of any better example, I don't remember having stumbled on a non context free defined logic ever).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. However, I think Wece logic could still be specified by context-free grammar by adding the new rule $S' \to SSS$ where $S'$ is my new starting point. Probably you want to mean something like $\phi \in \{\psi_1^n\psi_2^n\psi_3^n\psi_4^n : n > 0 \}$ (multiplication here means "&"), which is not context-free?

Comment: The rule you gave does not work since it does not force the three S to give the same thing. I aiming at $\{www|w\in\Sigma^*\}$ wich is not context free. But the logic you gave is also well defined and not context free (and also useless :D) and that was my point.

Comment: I see, you are right :)